# WebStorm - How to change the theme of the active bar

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I'm using the WebStorm IDE. I decided to change the theme, everything worked fine except for the active bar, the color theme of the active bar does not change:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the **Color Scheme** only -- it affects Editor (syntax colors) mainly + VCS File Status and some other aspects.

To change the whole window you need to change **GUI Theme** at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme` (HINT: search field helps a lot in narrowing it down).

[image]

You can also do that via `View | Quick Switch Scheme...` (which is a much faster way than going via Settings screen)

[image]